# Replace the value with the id in jquery condition

Tags: jquery

I have a input selection like this

```
            <div class="price section-content">
              <label>
                <input id=" price" name="price-option" type="radio" value="0">
                <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i>
                <span>Price</span>
              </label>
              <label>
                <input id="exchange" name="price-option" type="radio" value="2">
                <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i>
                <span>Exchange</span>
              </label>
              <label>
                <input id="donate" name="price-option" type="radio" value="1">
                <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i>
                <span>Donate 2</span>
              </label>
            </div>
```

that changes the input on click with via this code

```
  $('input[name="price-option"]').change(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == 0) {
      $('input#price').val('');
      $('input#price, #currency').attr('readonly', false);
    } else if ( $(this).val() == 1) {
      $('input#price').val(0);
      $('input#price, #currency').attr('readonly', true);
    } else if ( $(this).val() == 2) {
      $('input#price').val('');
      $('input#price, #currency').attr('readonly', true);
    }
  });
```

Right now, this is happening via value="0, 1 or 2) and i would like to know if the same result can be achieved by replacing in the jquery the value="" with the id of that value. If it is possible.

Comment: Protip: cache your objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to replace `value` comparison with `id` comparison, use `this.id` for getting the id's of the radio buttons.

```
      $('input[name="price-option"]').change(function(){      
   if(this.id == "price") {
      $('#priceInp').val('');
      $('#priceInp').attr('readonly', false);
    } else if ( this.id == "donate") {
      $('#priceInp').val(0);
      $('#priceInp').attr('readonly', true);
    } else if ( this.id == "exchange") {
      $('#priceInp').val('');
      $('#priceInp').attr('readonly', true);
    }
  });
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/5L0r04tf/

Comment: This is the closest to what i mean. It works ok if i select exchange or donate but will not work if i select price. Inside price input i have a input field and a currency check and i will not be  able to insert a price anymore. Looking by your code i see $('input#price').val(0); - is this ok or shulded be replaced as well?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are trying to set the value of a radio button to empty or zero. Also, you do not need input appended to id . Update the solution.

Comment: Please take a look at http://zara.mb-themes.com/item/new   at price area. That is what i try to achieve but changed into input + currency dropdown and buttons for Free or Check with seller.   That is actually  aconversion of the standard price field which allows input of numbers to result as price, which allows 0 and that will show as free and no numbers input and that will show as Check with seller. Standard function in osclass which is wrong because users do not know about such function.

Comment: You are missing the input type=text from your dom. Now i understood what you are trying to do. Updated the solution along with an example. Hopefully this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Please take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/Adyyda/xjnp8c4b/1/    In that, <?php ItemForm::price_input_text(); ?> generates <input id="price" type="text" value="" name="price" class="">  (i do not have access to it so i can only use it's id). That works fine for price and for free but not ok for Exchange. When i select that, the final ad will show Free so i guess that in the end, the $(this).val() == 2 reads the condition for price input (since it has 3 as mentioned) like 0 is price inserted, 1 is for Exchange and 2 for free. In any case, i have accepted your solution and Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
$('input[name="price-option"]').change(function(){
  if( $(this).val() == 0) {
    $('input#price, #currency').attr('readonly', false);
  } else if ( $(this).val() == 1) {
    $('input#price, #currency').attr('readonly', true);
  } else if ( $(this).val() == 2) {
    $('input#price, #currency').attr('readonly', true);
  }
  $('input#price').val($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Hello. Maybe i did not explain ok. I want to know if i can replace $(this).val() == 0) with #price  or ( $(this).val() == 1) with #donate. Thanks